# Android Emulator is not starting in AndroidStudio - Ubuntu-12.04 OS

Tags: android, android-emulator, ubuntu-12.04

[image]When i try to run hello world program in AndriodStudio (Ubuntu 32bit OS). I see below message in Console but emulator is not starting.

```
Waiting for device.
/home/yahooda/JAVA/android-studio/sdk/tools/emulator -avd test2 -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

When i am trying to open from terminal

```
yahooda@yahooda-System-Product-Name:~$ /home/yahooda/JAVA/android-studio/sdk/tools/emulator -avd test2
PANIC: Could not open: test2
```

Comment: How long do you wait? What happens if you enter that command at the shell prompt?

Comment: I waited more than 5 mins. I am new to ubuntu, i dontknow how to open through shell prompt.

Comment: I am currently logged into windows, so from memory: find a "terminal" icon on the desktop or in the menus, and open the terminal. Cut and paste the line you showed us above, and see what happens. Let us know the result.

Comment: PANIC: Could not open: test2 , I am getting this in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the Android Virtual Device Manager (you should have used it to create test2), to see the status of the test2 device.

If you cannot correct any problem, try creating a new AVD.

Comment: status of test2 device is available. I tried even creating new AVD but still no luck. I uploading photo of it.

Comment: i am going offline. I will reply u later.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android studio 1.3.2 on Ubuntu 15.04. When I tried running an AVD from studio, nothing happened. Even when I run my correct program from studio to use AVD, nothing appeared. No errors as well. And I did wait long enough to be sure that emulator never started.

When running the emulator from ~/Android/Sdk/tools folder and gave options like in this document: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html

There was bus error. KVM was properly set. After hours of figuring out I tried uninstalling Android SDK tools from Android SDK manager. And reinstalled them.

It started working. I hope this might help people who are looking for solution to similar problem.